# How to know ip camera address

Tags: linux, networking, ip

I have ip camera with static ip address preset. How can I know it ip using linux?

I connect camera direct to my notebook.

My system is
`Linux machine 3.5.7-gentoo #2 SMP`

```
ifconfig eth0  
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500  
        inet6 fe80::21e:ecff:fe18:854f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>  
        ether 00:1e:ec:18:85:4f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)  
        RX packets 35839  bytes 2150340 (2.0 MiB)  
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0  
        TX packets 1084  bytes 145354 (141.9 KiB)  
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Read device documentation if it is initial setup or scan your network with nmap if it is already in use.

Comment: Welcome on StackExchange. You don't provide enough information! It's really difficult for people to help you if you don't explain what is the structure of your network, what is specifically the problem you're trying to solve, what linux distribution do you use... Please read the FAQ and have a look to high-ranted questions to see the best practices of this site.

Comment: @lgeorget I try to be more specify, please correct me if it is not enough.

Comment: It's much better!

Answer (score 7):

If it has a static IP address preset and not configured to use DHCP by default, it probably still has. In this case, you should connect it to a private network (just a computer and your camera for example) with the same network and netmask to configure it.

If it uses DHCP, you can ping all your network and look in your ARP cache for the MAC address of your camera. For example:

```
nmap -sP 192.168.0.0/24
arp | grep <the MAC address with ':' as separator and lower case letters>
```

EDIT: (considering the information provided)

If you connect your camera directly to your notebook, you are able to access the camera configuration (it may be a web page, or a simple telnet menu...). In the manual of your camera, you can figure out what is your default camera's IP. You have to configure your notebook by setting a static address in the same network.

For example, if your camera's address is `192.168.0.1`, you can configure your notebook with `ifconfig 192.168.0.2/24 up`. You should then be able to ping your camera and modify its configuration (static IP address, DHCP setting, etc.). You'll then be able to connect your camera in the network you want.

Comment: I assume here that your network is `192.168.0.0/24` and that your distro tools are standard. You don't provide a lot of information...

Comment: Camera is already in use and default IP has changed. I can't connect to configuration web page because I don't know IP. And I don't know what IP and mask set by `ifconfig`.

Comment: That's the kind of information you should give when you ask a question. Well, then, common networks are `192.168.0.1/24`, `192.168.1.1/24`, `172.16.0.0/16`, and `10.0.0.0/8`. You can set your network to these values successively and do an `nmap` to look for your camera until you finally find it.

Answer (score 2):

The camera should have its MAC address written somewhere on it: this will be twelve characters long, possibly with colons between each pair of characters.

You can then use `nmap` to probe your subnet to populate your machine's ARP table, then look for a matching entry for your camera's MAC address you have.

```
$ nmap -sn 192.0.2.0/24      <-- replace with your subnet's address and size

Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-06-17 15:11 BST
Nmap scan report for 192.0.2.1
Host is up (0.00012s latency).
...

$ arp -an | grep -v incomplete
? (192.0.2.1) at 00:02:03:04:05:06     <-- list of MAC addresses
? (192.0.2.24) at 08:0a:0b:0c:0d:0e
```